# Formatting Date Using NSDateFormatter Not Working

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this `NSString` that has a date and time that I want to format:

`Jul 17, 2013 09:10 PM`

I want to format it like this:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

but it doesn't work.

This is the code I'm using:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:_dateToFormat];
NSLog(@"_date: %@", _date);

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSString *_newDate = [formatter stringFromDate:_date];
NSLog(@"_newDate: %@", _newDate);
```

`NSLog` returns:

```
_date: 2013-07-17 04:10:00 +0000
_newDate: 2013-07-17 04:10:00 +0000
```

Am I missing something? After formatting the date, I want to subtract 45 minutes from the formatted date using the code:

```
_newDate = [_date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*45];
NSLog(@"Subtracted date: %@", _newDate);
```

But this isn't my worry right now since the first step isn't working, which is to format the date from `NSString`. Any idea why it isn't working?

### Edit

Updated the typo on the code for dateByAddingInterval by changing _newDate with _date.

Comment: Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: If I had to make a guess I would say you did not post the code you were using. There is no way that _newDate is a NSString and you can run `[_newDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:]` at the same time. _newDate is not a NSString, it's a NSDate, which explains the output of your NSLog.

Comment: I did posted the code I'm using. If that's what you're referring to, I mistyped it by posting _newDate instead of _date. Even if I corrected it, it's still not working.

Comment: It's working just fine.  (Read up on timezones.)

Answer (score 2):

you are using `HH` and `a` in your dateFormat. `HH` means "hour in 24 hour format", and it looks like it takes precedence over `a`, the period (i.e. PM).

Use `@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"` with `hh`, which means "hour in 12 hour format" to convert your string into a NSDate.

---

```
NSString *_dateToFormat = @"Jul 17, 2013 09:10 PM"; // this is in local time zone! (mine is UTC+2)

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:_dateToFormat];
NSLog(@"wrong _date: %@", _date);

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
_date = [formatter dateFromString:_dateToFormat];
NSLog(@"correct _date: %@", _date);     // this is in UTC, not in local time zone!
NSLog(@"correct _date: %@", [_date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]); // this should be in your local timezone
```

Output:

```
  wrong _date: 2013-07-17 10:10:00 +0000
correct _date: 2013-07-17 19:10:00 +0000   (in my timezone: 21:10, or 09:10 PM)
correct _date: Wednesday, July 17, 2013, 9:10:00 PM Central European Summer Time
```

Keep in mind that printing a NSDate usually prints in UTC. So if your timezone is different the logged NSDate will not match your input date. It will be off by the offset between your timezone and UTC.

You can print `[_date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]` to see the time in your local timezone.

But this is just when you NSLog the NSDate. The NSDate is still correct, it's just the printed output that seems to be wrong.

---

To conclude, your code should look like this:

```
NSString *_dateToFormat = @"Jul 17, 2013 09:10 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];

// create date from string
NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:_dateToFormat];

// subtract 45 minutes
_date = [_date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*45];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
// turn date into string
NSString *_newDate = [formatter stringFromDate:_date];
NSLog(@"%@", _newDate);
```

Output: `2013-07-17 20:25`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't see that. I'll edit my code and use the lowercase h instead.

Comment: it will not work, that is not the mistake.just dont go read and answer.apply ur brain if u have any.

Comment: @Kasaname - I'm using my brain apparently and made it to work. See the edits I'll make on my post after posting this comment.

Comment: @jaytrixz I made a couple of edits. Also don't worry, I am the one without a brain, not you ;-)

Comment: @jaytrixz thats the copy of my answer i posted..then why the hell was i downvoted

Comment: @jaytrix - the comment was not for u . it was for the one who understood

Answer (score 2):

Since your dateString is in AM/PM format you will have to use

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
```

Comment: I edited it using the lowercase h and it still not formats it the way I wanted it.

Comment: @jaytrixz I worked out your code. It worked even when no locale was specified with hour format as `hh` but not with `HH`. If your dateString is in local timeZone everything should work. Another thing I can note is that in one log you are using NSDate and in other you are using NSString. Date log will be in UTC and in string log (converted value) will be in local time. All others are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 different formatters, one for converting the string to a date and a second for converting your date back to a string. The first should use the `en_US_POSIX` locale and the second should probably use the system (default) locale (but if you want to force a particular format then you can use `en_US_POSIX` here too).

Comment: I'll try this. What's the system default locale?

Comment: System default is whatever the user has configured in settings. If you don't set a locale on the formatter it will be used automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:_dateToFormat];

NSlog(@"Date: %@",_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

I managed to make it work using this code with the appropriate output logs:

```
NSString *oldDate = @"Jul 17, 2013 09:10 PM";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *_date = [formatter dateFromString:oldDate];
NSLog(@"_date: %@", _date);

_date = [_date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*45];
NSLog(@"_date2: %@", _date);

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSString *_newDate2 = [formatter stringFromDate:_date];
NSLog(@"_newDate2: %@", _newDate2);
```

Output:

```
_date: 2013-07-17 13:10:00 +0000
_newDate: 2013-07-17 21:10
_date2: 2013-07-17 12:25:00 +0000
_newDate2: 2013-07-17 20:25
```